# E: Unable to locate package xgraph error on Ubuntu 20.04 in virtual machine

Tags: networking, kubuntu, virtualbox, error-handling, ns2

I am working on ns2 software and need to install xgraph

When I put "sudo apt-get install xgraph" command it shows  the below message

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package xgraph**
please help.

Comment: That package is *deprecated* and only available on ESM release of Ubuntu now.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to locate package xgraph ... Ubuntu 20.04

The last usable package was the version used in Ubuntu 14.04:
`xgraph_12.1-17_amd64.deb`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idXGOZ0W5PmOlKM8p6_qlIRY6U5dJ1Q4/view?usp=share_link
Ref. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xgraph/
→ → http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xgraph/xgraph_12.1-17_amd64.deb

Download, and install:
`sudo apt install Downloads/xgraph_12.1-17_amd64.deb`

Comment: FYI: `rmadison` shows there was also a built for *xenial* or 16.04  (same package version though); `xgraph | 12.1-17 | xenial/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x`

Comment: thank you. I installed the older version of ubantu and its running properly.